# Google Maps API Directions - Move directions link to sidebar

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently when you click on a marker, a clickable get directions link comes up along with title and address.  I would also like the get directions link to appear on the sidebar as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
         }
     </style>

<style type='text/css'>
.text
{
width:300px;
height:600px;
background-color:white;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     

// Store Name[0],Address[1],Coordinates[2],Icon[3]

var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

 ];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {       
            zoom: 9,       
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),       
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
        });      
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      
  var marker, i;      
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found "+locations.length+" locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {         
            var coordStr = locations[i][2];
        var coords = coordStr.split(",");
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
            bounds.extend(pt);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({         
                            position: pt,         
                            map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3],
                            address: locations[i][1],
                            title: locations[i][0],
                            **html: locations[i][0]+"<br>"+locations[i][1]+"<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][1]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"**
                            });                              
            gmarkers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {         return function() 
            {           infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);         
            }       
        })
        (marker, i));     
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   

}

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
            customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,12);
            // get driving distance
            closest = closest.splice(0,12);
            calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,12);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
   var closest = [];
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"<br>";
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
     gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
     closest.sort(sortByDist);  
   }

   return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a,b) { 
 return (a.distance- b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request =    {
      origins: [pt],
      destinations: [],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    };
  for (var i=0; i < closest.length; i++) {
  request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

     var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);

        **outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][1]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"**
      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
      origin:origin,
      destination:destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script> 
   </head>
   <body>
   <table border="0"><tr><td>
     <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width:800px;"></div>
     </td><td>
     <div id="side_bar" class = 'text'> </div>
     </td></tr></table>

<input id="address" type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA"></input>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();"></input>
<div id="info"></div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

I tried to move from here:

```
html: locations[i][0]+"<br>"+locations[i][1]+"<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][1]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
```

to here:

```
outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][1]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"
```

I'm now able to have the get directions link appear in the sidebar, however the directions don't match up to correct title and address like they do from the marker.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to use the "sorted" version of the address, not the version in the input.  Your question is closed so I can't answer it right now, but it looks like it should be reopened shortly.

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vj0cpv0c/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much, works great!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "sorted" version of the address, not the version in the input.

```
// save title and address in record for sorting
for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
  results[i].title = closest[i].title;
  results[i].address = closest[i].address;
  results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
}
results.sort(sortByDistDM);
// use the stored values in the output to the sidebar
for (var i = 0;
  ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
  closest[i].setMap(map);
  outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"
}
```

sort function:

```
function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vj0cpv0c/10/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][2];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3],
      address: locations[i][1],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][1] + "<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + locations[i][1] + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, 12);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, 12);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
  }

  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);

        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"

      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
table,tr,td {
  height: 100%;
  }


.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width:400px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar" class='text'> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<div id="info"></div>
```